# alfresco-enterprise-5.0.2.5 Not able to install properly on my windows 7 machine

Tags: alfresco

Previously i was using Alfresco 5.0.d

But now i am trying to install alfresco-enterprise-5.0.2.5 on my machine.

But i am getting some errors while installing it first time.

please refer below attached image.

If any one has faced same issue or resolved it, then please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you have admin rights to install softwares? Try installing with local administrator account.

Comment: Ohh, Thanks for reply. i will try to re-install with admin rights

Comment: Actually here i am able to login, but on alfresco tomcat console its giving some errors related to solar.  So i don't think there will be any relation with admin rights. But even though i will try it once...

Comment: I think its because of port conflict.Somthink might be blocking postgresql port or alfresco tomcat port.Please put your full log.

Comment: Yes, please share your alresco.log and solr.log file.

Comment: As you're trying to install a paid-for enterprise version, why not just give Alfresco Support a ring and ask them for help? It's part of what you're paying for!